# How to draw a circle with on button click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I decided to try JavaScript graphics today and I managed to find a function called `draw()` which is supposed to get the drawing context from a canvas object and call some draw methods from a canvas object to draw a figure.

**Logic**

I hard coded a canvas html tag and gave it an `id`..
Accessed the canvas object from my JavaScript `draw()` function and then accessed the same canvas two dimension drawing context and called some shots on the drawing methods found in the two dimension drawing context object.

**Expectation**

I expected my code to draw a black circle on the canvas in the body tags when i click the draw button but there seems to a problem with the `draw()` function please help

```js
function draw() {
  //get the drawing canvas
  let canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  //check if the context returns true
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //get the co ordinates
    let X = canvas.width / 2;
    let Y = canvas.height / 2;
    //define the radius
    let R = 45;
    //begin drawing the circle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, R, O, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    //set the thickness of the draw print
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    //set the color of the draw print
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#111";
    //start drawing the object
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.mybutton {
  background: #964b00;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!--declare a canvas object we will use to draw the circle-->
<center><canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas></center>
<center><button class="mybutton" onclick="draw()">mybutton</button></center>
```

Comment: did your canvas draw?

Comment: Check out the error in your browser console. The `O` variable was not defined.

Comment: ctx.arc(X, Y, R, O, 2 * Math.PI, false);

on your code, I can see you didn't mention/declare the value of the "O" variable.

Comment: Please make it 0(zero).

Comment: So it was a typo, okay, Thanks, correcting

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed an undefined variable (O) for the sAngle paramater.

I assume you meant to pass 0 which will make it work (in radians 0 is at the third o'clock position of the arc's circle)

```js
function draw() {
  //get the drawing canvas
  let canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  //check if the context returns true
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //get the co ordinates
    let X = canvas.width / 2;
    let Y = canvas.height / 2;
    //define the radius
    let R = 45;
    //begin drawing the circle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    //set the thickness of the draw print
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    //set the color of the draw print
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#111";
    //start drawing the object
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.mybutton {
  background: #964b00;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!--declare a canvas object we will use to draw the circle-->
<center><canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas></center>
<center><button class="mybutton" onclick="draw()">mybutton</button></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please define the 'O' variable that's way gives the error .  add `let O =50` in `draw()`  you will get result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).